# Commutator of raising operator in angular momentum with partial derivative wrt z

Tags: angular-momentum, commutator, lie-algebra, spherical-harmonics, special-functions

While fiddling around with certain commutation relations, i noticed the following relation while using spherical coordinates.
What could this relation mean intuitively? Let me know if any information could be provided related to this relation. I've never encountered such a relation in texts dealing with special functions. I'm using these relations to understand solutions of laplace equation and spherical harmonics better.

$$[ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}, L_+ ] = ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} )$$

Comment: Hint: The momentum operator is a  *vector operator* and the angular momentum operator generates *rotations*.

Answer (score 2):

You are aiming to show
$$
[p_z,L_x+iL_y]= p_x+ip_y.
$$
Have set $\hbar=1$ for simplicity.

This [near duplicate answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/403933/66086) works out
$$
[p_i, L_j]   = 
 i \epsilon_{ijm}p_m,
$$
yielding your answer.

As @Hyperon comments, momentum is a vector operator:  ***L*** rotates it like a vector.

Practice by  operating with your relation on [$Y_1^0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#%E2%84%93_=_1).