Possible errata Landau and Lifshitz in $\S29$ Matrix elements of vectors in Quantum Mechanics Third Edition
Context
L&L write,

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be some vector physical quantity characterizing a closed system... In the particular case where $\mathbf{A}$ is the radius vector of the particle... we find the commutation rules
$$
\left[\widehat{L}_i,\widehat{A}_k\right] = i\varepsilon_{ikl} \widehat{A}_l.\tag{29.4}
$$

I have attempted to prove this. I do not obtain this result.
My attempt
Let $\widehat{\mathbf{A}} = \begin{bmatrix}\widehat{A}_x  ,\widehat{A}_z,\widehat{A}_z\end{bmatrix}$, where $\widehat{A}_x =  {A}_{xx}\widehat{x}$,  $\widehat{A}_y = {A}_{yy}\widehat{y}$, and  $\widehat{A}_z = {A}_{zz}\widehat{z}$.
Then, for example,
\begin{align}
\left[ \widehat{p}_x,\mathbf{\widehat{A}} \right]\psi 
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[ \widehat{p}_x, \widehat{A}_x \right]\psi 
\\
\left[ \widehat{p}_x,\widehat{A}_y \right]\psi 
\\
\left[ \widehat{p}_x, \widehat{A}_z\right]\psi 
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \widehat{A}_x \widehat{p}_x\left[  \psi  \right] 
+
\psi \widehat{p}_x  \left[ \widehat{A}_x \right]
-
\widehat{A}_x  \widehat{p}_x\left[ \psi  \right]
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \psi\widehat{p}_x \widehat{A}_x
\\
  \psi\widehat{p}_x \widehat{A}_y
\\
  \psi\widehat{p}_x \widehat{A}_z
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-  \psi i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(A_{xx}x+0y+0z \right)
\\
-  \psi i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(0x+A_{yy}y+0z\right)
\\
-  \psi i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(0x+0y+A_{zz}z\right)
\end{bmatrix} 
\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-  \psi i\hbar  A_{xx}  
\\
0
\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Thus,
$$
\left[ \widehat{p}_i, \widehat{A}_k \right] = -i
\hbar A_{kk}\delta_{ik}. \tag{1}
$$
Next,
\begin{align*}
\left[\widehat{L}_x ,\widehat{A}_y\right]\psi
=&
\left[\left(\widehat{y}\widehat{p}_z-\widehat{z}\widehat{p}_y\right)  ,\widehat{A}_y\right]\psi
\\
=&
\left[ \widehat{y}\widehat{p}_z    ,\widehat{A}_y \right]\psi
-
\left[ \widehat{z}\widehat{p}_y  ,\widehat{A}_y \right]\psi
\\
=&
\widehat{y}\left[ \widehat{p}_z    ,\widehat{A}_y \right]\psi
+
\left[ \widehat{y}    ,\widehat{A}_y \right]\widehat{p}_z\psi
-
\widehat{z}\left[ \widehat{p}_y  ,\widehat{A}_y \right]\psi
-
\left[ \widehat{z} ,\widehat{A}_y \right]\widehat{p}_y \psi
\\
=&
-
\widehat{z}\left[ \widehat{p}_y  ,\widehat{A}_y \right]\psi
\\
=&
i\hbar
\widehat{z}   A _{yy}  \psi
\end{align*}
Since, in general,
$$
i\hbar
\widehat{z}   A _{yy}  \psi
\neq
i\hbar
\widehat{z}   A _{zz}  \psi,
$$
therefore I do not find the same result as that of Landau and Lifshitz.
Questions
Did I get this wrong? If so, what did I get wrong?  How can I make this right?
[UPDATEs: Following the answer and comments therein, what appears to be wrong here is that the result in L&L holds only for the case where $\widehat{\mathbf{A}} = \widehat{\mathbf{r}}$. If a future reader stumbles upon this thread at a later time and feels otherwise, I would welcome any comments or an additional solution.]

^ Yep. And for that reason I think that it is best style for downvoters to leave comments, because this helps users know how to improve posts for them to be well-received (if there is any problem with their post at all).

I think you lost the derivative of $A_{xx}$ in the last steep of evaluating the commutator ($A_{xx}$ instead of $\partial_x A_{xx}$. Also $k_{yy}\rightarrow A_{yy}$.

@Roger V. Hi. Ugh, I wish I knew where you were referrring to. Are you referrring to a location after Eq 1?

Just before Eq. 1 - the last equality of three-storey expression. Ah, no I am wrong - $A_{xx}$ is a constant.

Well, in the particular case of a radius vector we have $A_{xx}=A_{yy}=A_{zz}=1$ by definition.

Are you suggesting that $A_{xx}$ is not a constant? My understanding is that $A_{xx}$ is a constant. Thus, the product rule of calculus is not applicable. If you feel that I made a mistake, then you are welcome to make an edit to the question (or else write the correction in a comment below.) Thanks

I mean it is a prefactor of $x$, rather than $x$ itself. As Landau says elsewhere in the same volume, it is easier to derive a result oneself than to follow a derivation.

Why do you put $\widehat{A}x =  {A}{xx}\widehat{x}$? Shouldn't you have $\widehat{A}x =  {A}{x}\widehat{x}$?

@jim, hi. In the veign of a matrix of transformation I use the notation .

The identity to use is:
$$[p_i,r_j]=-i\hbar\delta_{ij}$$
You are doing something wrong:
$$[L_z,r_x]=[r_xp_y-r_yp_x,r_x]=r_x[p_y,r_x]-r_y[p_x,r_x]$$
$$=0-r_y (-i\hbar \delta_{x,x})=i\hbar r_y$$
It works. Now for every component combination we get:
$$[\epsilon_{ilj}r_lp_j,r_k]=\epsilon_{ilj}r_l[p_j,r_k]=-i\hbar\epsilon_{ilj}r_l\delta_{jk}$$
$$=-i\hbar\epsilon_{ilk}r_l=i\hbar\epsilon_{ikl}r_l$$
Comment
As the comments have suggested that there are some other examples of $\mathbf A$ that follow $[L_i,A_k]=i\hbar\epsilon_{ikl}A_k$ like momentum $\mathbf p$, angular momentum $\mathbf L$ itself and spin $\mathbf S$ (if we change $\mathbf L\to\mathbf J=\mathbf L+\mathbf S$). If a given operator has this property, it is called a vector operator, more specifically it is valid if the operator transforms as
$$U_R^\dagger\mathbf  AU_R=R\mathbf A$$
for the unitary transformation $U_R$ related to a rotation matrix $R$,, i.e $U_R(\theta)=\exp(-i\theta \hat{n}\cdot \mathbf L/\hbar)$ around axis unit vector $\hat{n}$ and angle $\theta$.
It does not work with all vectors-like operators like the magnetic vector operator $\mathbf A(\mathbf r)$, see:

Possible distinction between operator-valued scalar & vectors functions in QM


@MichaelLevy I have added a more specific identity

Mauricio, the question you are answering is not the question being asked.  The question is $[\widehat{L}_i,\widehat{A}j] = \varepsilon{ijk}\widehat{A}_k$; the question is not $[\widehat{L}_i,\widehat{r}j] = \varepsilon{ijk}\widehat{r}_k$

@MichaelLevy read the statement of the problem "Let $\mathbf A$ be some vector physical quantity characterizing a closed system... In the particular case where $\mathbf A$ is the radius vector of the particle we find the commutation rules"

Ok. you are stating that $\widehat{\mathbf{A}}$ is nothing more than $\widehat{\mathbf{r}}$.

@MichaelLevy yeah otherwise it does not work.

The same commutation relations hold for any vector operator $\hat{\vec A}$ (if $\hat{\vec L}$ is understood to be the total angular momentum). See, e.g. the answer by Ruffolo or my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/403927/angular-and-linear-momentum-operators-commutation/403933#403933 (which includes a derivation of the result for spatial rotations – extending it to total angular momentum and including spin degrees of freedom is pretty straightforward).

I don't know what is wrong with your reasoning, since it seems to return the right result in the special case where $A_{yy}=A_{zz}$. That said, I never saw this approach, and I searched in Landau'book and I didn't find it there either.

The approach that I know, and it could be used with other symmetry transformations, is to observe how the vector $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$ behaves under the symmetry transformation. It could be done with the help of the Principle of Correspondence, if you know how the Classical counter-part transform under the considered transformation.
In Classical mechanics, any vector $\mathbf A$ subjected to a rotation $R_n(\theta)$ in direction $\mathbf n$ will transform like
$$
\mathbf{A'} = R_n(\theta)\mathbf A = \mathbf A + (\mathbf n \times \mathbf A)\sin\theta + (\mathbf n\times \mathbf n\times A )(1-\cos \theta).\tag{1}
$$
For small angle $\theta$, we could write
$$
\mathbf {A'}= R_n(\theta)\mathbf A = \mathbf A + \theta(\mathbf n\times A) \tag{2}
$$
Now, by the Principle of Correspondence, by applying the rotation $U_n(\theta)$ over the operator $\mathbf{\hat A}$, we should get the same result as in the classical case
$$
\mathbf{\hat A'}= U_n(\theta)\mathbf{\hat A}U_n^\dagger(\theta) = \mathbf{\hat A} + \theta \mathbf n \times \mathbf{\hat A}.\tag{3}
$$
But we know that $U_n(\theta) = e^{-i\theta \mathbf n \cdot \mathbf{\hat L}/\hbar}$, and for small angles we could write
$$
\left( \mathbb I - \frac{i\theta}{\hbar} L_n \right ) \mathbf{\hat A} \left ( \mathbb I + \frac{i\theta}{\hbar} L_n\right) = \mathbf{\hat A} + \theta \mathbf n \times \mathbf{\hat A},
$$
Where $L_n \equiv \mathbf n\cdot \mathbf{\hat L}$. Opening the l.h.s. and keeping just the first order terms, we get
$$
[L_n,A_m ] = i\mathcal{E}_{nmk} A_k.
$$

We could do it in a more formal way. Without any approximation, It is possible to use the  first equation to write
$$
[U_n(\theta),\mathbf{\hat A}] = \sin(\theta)(\mathbf n\times \mathbf{\hat A} )U_n(\theta) + (1-\cos\theta)(\mathbf n\times \mathbf n \times \mathbf{\hat A})U_n(\theta).\tag{4}
$$
Take the derivative w.r.t. $\theta$ and the limit $\theta\to 0$, and remember that the generators of any Lie group are defined as ${\partial U\over \partial \theta}|_{\theta=0}$. For rotations, they are $\frac{1}{i\hbar}L_n$.

You could be unsatisfied because it's not the way you are trying to show it, and maybe because I'm assuming a representation for rotations in QT. The rotation operator in QM is defined that way, and it gives a precise meaning for vector operators and tensor operators.
I hope it helps.

EDIT: if you accept equation (1) as being true, by correspondence we should have the same for expectation values
$$
\langle \mathbf{\hat A'}\rangle = \langle \mathbf{\hat A}\rangle + (\mathbf n \times \langle\mathbf A\rangle)\sin\theta + (\mathbf n\times \mathbf n\times \langle \mathbf A\rangle )(1-\cos \theta).
$$
Now, we know that $\langle \mathbf{\hat A}\rangle = \langle \Psi'|\mathbf{\hat A}|\Psi'\rangle = \langle \Psi| U_n \mathbf{\hat A}U_n^\dagger|\Psi\rangle$, so equation above implies
$$
U_n\mathbf{\hat A} U_n^\dagger = \mathbf{\hat A} + (\mathbf n \times \mathbf{\hat A})\sin\theta + (\mathbf n\times \mathbf n\times \mathbf{\hat A} )(1-\cos \theta).
$$
If you apply $U_n$ on the right hand side and subtract both sides by $\mathbf{\hat A}U_n$, you get equation (4).

Can you elucidate your foundation for writing Eq. 3?   What claims are necessary---a priori---in order to assert the veracity of Eq. 3?

The foundation lies in the fact that, based on the Classical result, we know how rotations act in vectors in the Classical case. We impose that the quantum representation of rotations should act similar over the quantum counterpart of those vectors

Similar to my last comment, it would be helpful to state any claims that are necessary---a priori---in otder to assert the veracity of Eq. 4. In addition, I believe it would be helpful to show a few more steps prior to writing Eq 4

Mauricio claims that at about  9:45 AM  on Dec 11 2024 that the result does not hold if $\widehat{\mathbf{A}}$ is not the radial vector $\widehat{\mathbf{r}}$. Yet, using your method it seems to hold. That is a curious distinction.

You should read about tensorial operators.
